# Does the closed convex hull of a compact set in the interior of a convex cone is still contained in the interior of the cone?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls, convex-cone

Let $C$ be a convex cone in a Banach space $X$ with nonempty interior. The set $A\subset {\rm Int}C$ is a compact subset, where ${\rm Int}C$ means the interior of $C$. Denote the closed convex hull of $A$ as $\overline{{\rm Co}(A)}$. Do we have $\overline{{\rm Co}(A)}\subset {\rm Int}C$?

Comment: I know that ${\rm Int C}$ is a convex subset of $X$. Hence ${\rm Co}(A)\subset {\rm Int C}$. However, ${\rm Co}(A)$ may not be compact in an infinite-dimentional Banach space $X$, but it is precompact.  $\overline{{\rm Co}(A)}$ must be compact. But does  $\overline{{\rm Co}(A)}\subset {\rm Int C}$?

Comment: I guess this is not true. But I can't find a counterexample for which in a Banach space $X$, there is an open convex subset $B$ and a compact suset $A\subset B$ such that $\overline{{\rm Co}(A)}\not\subset B$.

Comment: Any ideas, comments will be greatly appreciated！

Comment: Perhaps studying the function $f(x)=\inf_{y\notin B} \|x-y\|$  helps ? The function is bounded away from $0$ on $A.$ I suspect it is bounded away from $0$ on the convex hull of $A,$ due to the convexity of $B,$ and hence on the closure of the convex hull of $A.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $$f(x)=\inf_{x\notin C}\|x-y\|.$$ This function is continuous. Since $A\subset C$ is compact and $C$ is open we get $$f(a)\ge \delta >0,\ \ a\in A.$$ Therefore for any $a\in A$ the closed ball $B(a,\delta)=\{x\in X\,:\, \|x-a\|\le \delta\}$ is contained in $C.$ Let ${\rm conv}(A)$ denote the convex hull of $A.$ This set consists of elements of the form
$$y=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k a_k,\qquad n\in \mathbb{N},\ \lambda_k\ge 0, \ a_k\in A,\ \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k=1.\qquad (*)$$ We claim that $f(y)\ge \delta$ for $y\in {\rm conv}(A).$ Fix $y\in {\rm conv }A$ of the form $(*).$ Then
\begin{multline*} C\supset \lambda_1B(a_1,\delta)+\ldots + \lambda_nB(a_n,\delta) 
= [\lambda_1 a_1+\lambda_1\delta\, B(0,1)]+\ldots + [\lambda_n a_n+\lambda_n\delta\, B(0,1)] \\
=y +\delta[\lambda_1B(0,1)+\ldots +\lambda_nB(0,1)]=y+\delta B(0,1)=B(y,\delta).
\end{multline*}
On the way we have used a simple fact that  $aB(0,1)+bB(0,1)=(a+b)B(0,1)$ for $a,b\ge 0.$

Thus $f(y)\ge \delta$ for $y\in {\rm conv}(A).$ Since the function $f$ is continuous the inequality $f(y)\ge \delta$ holds for $y\in \overline{{\rm conv}(A)}.$ Hence $\overline{{\rm conv}(A)}\subset C.$

Comment: Thank you very much! I see. It turns out to be so geometrically intuitive!